# how to change admin password for Sonatype Nexus Using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have installed the nexus using playbook from the below url:

```
http://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/nexus-3.18.1-01-unix.tar.gz
```

For first time login the default password admin/admin123 **doesn't** work, however it prompts me to copy the password from file /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password and login.
I am able to login with this password mentioned in admin.password.

How can i use the password mentioned in admin.password file to automate and change the password for 'admin' user over url http://localhost:8081, **using** playbook?

Comment: you can do it using copy and replace module for it

Comment: how to do it for the url which needs login, can you be more specific

Comment: You can add a property to $workdir/etc/nexus.properties to disable the randomization of passwords:  nexus.security.randompassword=false  .. or you can pass that in as a java system property.

Comment: Tough it makes sense, I preferred to use lower version of nexus where default password is admin/admin123, thank you for the answer, will try it again when i go back the the newer version of nexus.

Comment: @ rseddon, I have validated, the solution works perfectly to use make use of default password admin123. thank you